# Test Class Coverage On Field Set By Trigger

Tags: code-coverage, opportunity

I have a trigger that is effectively checking a custom list to match the Close Date with the Start/End dates for weeks so a custom field is populated with the text of the Start and End dates.

Trigger:

```
trigger CloseWeekUpdate on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
Try{
    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
        if(opp.CloseDate != NULL){
            system.debug('opp.CloseDate = ' + opp.CloseDate);
            for(CloseDateWeek__c rec : CloseDateWeek__c.getAll().values()){
                if (opp.CloseDate >= rec.WeekStartDate__c && opp.CloseDate <= rec.WeekEndDate__c){
                    system.debug('rec.WeekStartDate__c = ' + rec.WeekStartDate__c);
                    system.debug('rec.WeeEndDate__c = ' + rec.WeekEndDate__c);
                    opp.Close_Week__c = rec.WeekStartDate__c.format() + ' - ' + rec.WeekEndDate__c.format();
                    system.debug('rec.Close_Week__c = ' + opp.Close_Week__c);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Catch(Exception Ex){
    system.debug('Exception Details = ' + Ex);
}
```

I have built a test class to insert a test Opportunity and I am getting to 50% but unable to get higher, how do I get the class to test line 9, 12 and 14 since these are the three it is telling me is failing.

Lines that are not testing:

- for(CloseDateWeek__c rec : CloseDateWeek__c.getAll().values()){
- if (opp.CloseDate >= rec.WeekStartDate__c && opp.CloseDate <= rec.WeekEndDate__c){
- opp.Close_Week__c = rec.WeekStartDate__c.format() + ' - ' + rec.WeekEndDate__c.format();

Here is the Test class I have:

```
    @isTest
public class TestCloseWeekUpdate {
    static testMethod void testCloseWeek(){
        Opportunity to = new Opportunity();
        to.Name = 'Test Name';
        to.CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2020,06,06);
        to.StageName = 'Closed Won';
        to.Start_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2020,06,01);
        to.Type = 'New Business';
        to.Market__c = 'Large';
        to.Premium__c = TRUE;
        to.Startup_Needed__c = 'Yes';
        insert to;
        test.startTest();
        try{
            to.Close_Week__c = '5/31/2020 - 6/6/2020';
        }
        Catch (Exception ee){}
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Any help with getting that last 3 lines covered is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The very first thing you should do is remove those exception-swallowing `catch` blocks. They are going to make your debugging process much more difficult, yield false positives, and potentially harm user data.

Comment: It would help if you could [edit] to denote which lines are which. By my count line 9 is a System.debug() statement.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the catch block, I cannot edit but the lines in question are:
if (opp.CloseDate >= rec.WeekStartDate__c && opp.CloseDate <= rec.WeekEndDate__c){

and

opp.Close_Week__c = rec.WeekStartDate__c.format() + ' - ' + rec.WeekEndDate__c.format();

Comment: @DavidReed I added the three lines in the main post that are the issue if you have any ideas on what to add to the test class to get coverage.

Comment: `CloseDateWeek__c` is presumably a custom setting - you need to mock these (DML insert) in the test class; custom settings are not considered as metadata and hence don't exist in a test context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue to be I needed to also declare the custom list values using the following:

```
    CloseDateWeek__c cdw1 = new CloseDateWeek__c();
    cdw1.WeekStartDate__c = Date.newInstance(2020, 05, 31);
    cdw1.WeekEndDate__c = Date.newInstance(2020, 06, 06);
    cdw1.Name = 'Week Test';
```

Once I had the list values declared as well as the Opportunity values that gave me the full coverage.